# About convergence and behavior of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

In my master thesis, I'm trying to prove the following limit:
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_0^1 \frac{\left(\ln\left(\frac{\epsilon}{1-x}+1\right)\right)^\alpha}{x^\beta(1-x)^\gamma}\,\mathrm{d}x=0,$$
where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in (0,1)$.

Assigning some numerical values to $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and $\epsilon$ in the Wolfram, I could perceive such convergence does indeed seem to happen.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Does Lebesgue Dominated convergence not work?

Comment: Is the power $\alpha$ over the entire log? As in, is it $\log( (f(x))^{\alpha}) $ or $(\log (f(x)) )^{\alpha}$

Comment: It is over the entire log. I clarify it now.

Comment: Ok you can use the monotone convergence Theorem and you only need to show that your function is integrable for some $\varepsilon>0$

Comment: It is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\frac1{1-x}=y$, then $\mathrm d x=y^{-2}\,\mathrm d y$ and $x=\frac{y-1}{y}$, so
$$
\int_{0}^1\frac{\left(\ln \left(\frac\epsilon {1-x}+1\right)\right)^{\alpha }}{x^{\beta }(1-x)^{\gamma }}\,\mathrm d x=\int_1^{\infty } \frac{y^{\beta +\gamma -2}}{(y-1)^{\beta }}\left(\ln \left(\epsilon y+1\right)\right)^{\alpha }\,\mathrm d y
$$
Note that $\ln(x+1)< x$ for all $x>0$, then we have that
$$
\begin{align*}
0&\leqslant \int_1^2 \frac{y^{\beta +\gamma -2}}{(y-1)^{\beta }}\left(\ln \left(\epsilon y+1\right)\right)^{\alpha }\,\mathrm d y\\
&<\epsilon^{\alpha }\int_1^2 \frac{y^{\alpha+\beta +\gamma -2}}{(y-1)^{\beta }}\,\mathrm d y\\
&<\epsilon ^{\alpha }\int_1^2\frac2{(y-1)^{\beta }}\,\mathrm d y\\
&=\frac{2\epsilon ^{\alpha }}{1-\beta },\quad \forall \alpha ,\beta,\gamma  \in (0,1)
\end{align*}
$$
Also note that $\lim_{x\to \infty }\frac{x^c}{\ln(x+1)}=\infty $ for all $c>0$, therefore for any chosen $c>0$ there is some $M>2$ such that $x^c>\ln(x+1)$ for all $x>M$, then
$$
\begin{align*}
0&\leqslant \int_M^\infty  \frac{y^{\beta +\gamma -2}}{(y-1)^{\beta }}\left(\ln \left(\epsilon y+1\right)\right)^{\alpha }\,\mathrm d y\\
&\leqslant \int_M^{\infty } \frac{\epsilon ^{c\alpha}y^{c\alpha +\beta +\gamma -2}}{(y-1)^{\beta }}\,\mathrm d y\\
&<\epsilon ^{c\alpha}\int_M^{\infty } \frac{y^{c\alpha +\beta +\gamma -2}}{(y-1)^{\beta }}\cdot \frac{(y-1)^{\beta }}{y^{\beta }}\cdot \sup_{t\geqslant M}\frac{t^{\beta }}{(t-1)^{\beta }}\,\mathrm d y\\
&<\epsilon ^{c\alpha}2^{\beta }\int_M^{\infty } y^{c\alpha +\gamma -2}\,\mathrm d y\\
&<\frac{\epsilon ^{c\alpha}2^{c\alpha +\beta+\gamma -1}}{1-c\alpha-\gamma } ,\quad \forall \alpha ,\beta, \gamma \in(0,1)
\end{align*}
$$
for $c>0$ such that $1-c\alpha-\gamma>0$. Therefore, because the integral in the region $[2,M]$ is proper, we can conclude that the limit is zero.

Comment: I just read your proof. I think we don't need Dominated Convergence Theorem since you estimated the integral and have kept the dependence of $\epsilon$ explicit. Thank you!

Comment: @M1123 you are right, we dont need it! I didnt noticed, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution: As already said, we just need to prove the convergence for some value of $\epsilon>0$ and then apply Monotone Convergence Theorem. So, let's prove to $\epsilon=1$.

Let $\kappa>0$ such that $\gamma+\kappa\alpha<1$ and rewrite
$$\frac{\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+1\right)\right)^\alpha}{x^{\beta}(1-x)^{\gamma}}=\frac{f(x)^\alpha}{x^{\beta}(1-x)^{\gamma+\kappa\alpha}},$$
where
$$f(x)=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+1\right)}{(1-x)^{-\kappa}}, \quad x \in (0,1).$$
Observe that $\lim_{x \to 1^-}f(x)=0$ (since $\lim_{u \to +\infty}\ln(u)/u^\kappa=0$ for any $\kappa>0$) and $f(0)=\ln(2)$. Therefore $f$ is bounded on $(0,1)$ and
$$\int_0^1\frac{\left(\ln\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+1\right)\right)^\alpha}{x^{\beta}(1-x)^{\gamma}}\,\mathrm{d}x\leq \int_0^1\frac{f(x)^\alpha}{x^{\beta}(1-x)^{\gamma+\kappa\alpha}}\mathrm{d}x\leq M^\alpha\int_0^1x^{-\beta}(1-x)^{-\gamma-\kappa\alpha}\mathrm{d}x=M^\alpha\textbf{B}(1-\beta,1-\gamma-\kappa\alpha),$$
where $M=\max_{0<x<1}f(x)$ and $\textbf{B}(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Beta function.

Is the proof correct?
Thank you all.